# Can I DRY SQL? How do I call two SQL scripts inside a BEGIN ... COMMIT?

Tags: sql, postgresql

So I have two SQL files. However, I would like to create a third file that wraps both scripts in a `BEGIN ... COMMIT` block.

---

file_1.sql

```
BEGIN;
    CREATE TABLE ....;
COMMIT;
```

file_2.sql

```
BEGIN;
    CREATE TABLE .....;
COMMIT;
```

desired_file.sql

```
BEGIN;
   (run file_1)
   (run file_2)
COMMIT;
```

is this possible?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5237198/transactsql-to-run-another-transactsql-script

Comment: @Matt Er, Microsoft SQL Server T-SQL isn't the same thing as PostgreSQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `psql`'s `\i`.

```
BEGIN;
\i file1
\i file2
COMMIT;
```