# SQLCMD Session Run SQL Script

Tags: sql-server, sqlcmd

I'm still pretty new to SQL Server but have a ton of experience with Oracle. How do I run a SQL script while I'm inside a SQLCMD session? Is their something analogous to "SQL>@C:[mypath]\myscript.sql" (Oracle) for SQL Server?

I'm sick of opening scripts and running them using bloated SQL Server Studio.

Comment: You don't like SSMS?

Comment: SSMS is an awesome tool and you should learn to use it. Just leave it running to avoid the start-up time. Open a script (or drag and drop a file into it), hit F5, and it runs. You have all sorts of analysis tools available too, examining plans, and browsing the database at your finger tips too. A good SQL Server developer lives in SSMS.

Answer (score 0):

`sqlcmd -i file` executes a file.

Can't recommend enough to check all the options in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility).

Answer (score 0):

I found what I was looking for. You can use this in SQLCMD and in SSMS Query as long as you open it up in "SQLCMD Mode"

```
:r [path]\myscript.sql
```

[TransactSQL to run another TransactSQL script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5237198/transactsql-to-run-another-transactsql-script])

Thanks for your responses. Much thanks.