# Scheduled and chained execution of SQL Files

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Given following SQL files:

*First,
Second,
Third,
Fourth*

Each containing random SQL queries.

Is there a way for me to link them together to execute one after another?
Run *First*, then *First* will automatically call *Second* when it's completed, then it will call *Third* etc.

Comment: create a main sql script that will call each script sequentially. run that main sql instead.

Comment: Possible [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5237198/transactsql-to-run-another-transactsql-script)

Comment: What do you mean by SQL *Files*?  Do you mean you have text files containing SQL statements and you want to call them in succession? Or do you simply mean you have several queries that you want to run in sequence, and they don't necessarily have to load from files?

Comment: @Tim SQL files - I mean files with SQL statements.  I want to call them in succession from different files.

Comment: @FerdinandGaspar - can you point me to some resource on how to do that?

Comment: Check @Khalil's provided link.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TransactSQL to run another TransactSQL script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5237198/transactsql-to-run-another-transactsql-script)