# run .sql file automatically by maintenance plan

Tags: sql, sql-server, maintenance-plan

I have an ordinary SQL Query (insert ... / update...) I run from daily manually in SQL Management Studio. In some cases the query Need to be improved.

However I want to execute the SQL Statement in maintenance plan to avoid Manual work. This works fine, too.

However having same Query stored in a .SQL file and additinally in maintenance plan is no good. After changing the query in .SQL file I have to update the maintenance plan, too.

This would be solved if I could put into the maintenance plan the command "run \myserver\queries\updatethis.sql"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TransactSQL to run another TransactSQL script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5237198/transactsql-to-run-another-transactsql-script)

Comment: The other Posts are different as they deal with running script in SSMS in Editor. Question is to run it in Maintenance plan.