# Incorrect syntax near @sql_file.sql in another sql_file.sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to execute some SQL file that contain a lot of SQL files inside. Just as a `main.sql` that contains all the others that should be executed.

**main.sql** :

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON;
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON;
SET ANSI_PADDING ON;

@new_instance.sql
@new_instance_tbl.sql
@new_instance_views.sql
@new_instance_tbl_configs.sql
```

When I open the file in my SQL Server, the red underline appears:

> Incorrect syntax near '@new_instance.sql'

and then if I try to execute this, the same failure appears, so...

How can I execute different "included" `.sql` files from one main SQL file?

Comment: You appear to think SQL is a scripting language; it isn't and it doesn't work like one. A SQL file isn't run, the contents of the file is read, and then sent to the data engine to be run locally on the instance. Other files in the folder the SQL file was saved in are irrelevant, as it's not a "file being run". SQL isn't run like a C# application or Powershell script.

Comment: Are you using SSMS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio) you can [enable SQLCMD Mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/scripting/edit-sqlcmd-scripts-with-query-editor?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15)

However, the syntax for referencing and executing external files is a bit different, see this answer to: [TransactSQL to run another TransactSQL script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5237250/1690217)

```
:r C:\Scripts\Script1.sql
:r C:\Scripts\Script2.sql
:r C:\Scripts\Script3.sql
```

Comment: You beat me to it. Adding that SQLCMD scripts can also be executed using the SQLCMD command-line utility (e.g.  `SQLCMD -S YourServer -E -I -i "C:\Scripts\main.sql"`).